# Designing 1-to-2 demultiplexing circuit with a custom truth table

Tags: digital-logic

I'm trying to build a circuit with following truth table with CMOS logic.

Pins are:

- `I` and `A` are inputs
- `D0` and `D1` are outputs
- `A` is a line select GPIO pin (1 for `D0`, 0 for`D1`)
- `I` is input level (when `D0` is "selected" `D1` level is set to 1 and vice versa)

I have figured out that `D1` is simply "`I` or `A`" but `D0` output is more difficult.

What is the general method of breaking down the problem in smaller pieces ?

[image: img]

```
I   A || D0  D1
1   1 ||  1   1
0   1 ||  0   1
1   0 ||  1   1
0   0 ||  1   0
```

EDIT: here's the solution. Any change to make it even simpler ?
[circuit simulator link](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/#%24+0+5.0E-6+10.20027730826997+50+5.0+50%0AI+240+96+336+96+0+0.5%0Aw+272+128+336+128+0%0A152+336+112+448+112+0+2+0.0%0Aw+272+128+240+128+0%0AM+448+112+496+112+0+2.5%0AL+208+96+128+96+0+1+false+5.0+0.0%0AL+240+192+240+240+0+0+false+5.0+0.0%0Ax+129+75+204+81+0+24+Input%3A+I%0Ax+232+281+316+287+0+24+Input%3A+A%0A152+336+176+432+176+0+2+5.0%0AM+432+176+496+176+0+2.5%0Aw+240+176+240+192+0%0Aw+336+192+240+192+0%0Aw+240+128+240+160+0%0Aw+240+160+240+176+0%0Aw+240+96+224+96+0%0Aw+224+96+208+96+0%0Aw+224+96+224+160+0%0Aw+224+160+336+160+0%0A)

Comment: D0 is `A&I'`, it takes an inverter (') and an AND gate (&)

Comment: @clabacchio You forgot to invert the result, (A&I')' = A'+I

Comment: @BrunoFerreira indeed :)

Comment: This is how it looks like. Any chance to make it even simpler ? I added link into the first post.

Comment: Why don't you try to use the built-in simulator? It's easier to visualize

Comment: actually I have. The 'circuit simulator link' should open a java applet with the logic circuit